# How to build regex for finding words that start with `\n` and letter and end with digit OR word?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Here's an example of string, spacing after digit could be different.

```py
product_list = 'Buy:\n Milk \nYoughurt 4 \nBread  \nSausages 4     \nBanana '
```

I want to build a regexp with the following output:

```py
import re

re.findall(r'some pattern', product_list)
['Milk', 'Youghurt 4', 'Bread', 'Sausages 4', 'Banana']
```

This is what I thought it should look like. However, it returns empty list:

```py
re.findall(r'\n(\w+\w$))', product_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use a non-regex (a regex seems expensive), if you can guarantee similar pattern of input:

```
list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), product_list.split('\n')))[1:]
```

**Code**:

```
product_list = 'Buy:\n Milk \nYoughurt 4 \nBread  \nSausages 4     \nBanana '

print(list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), product_list.split('\n')))[1:])
# ['Milk', 'Youghurt 4', 'Bread', 'Sausages 4', 'Banana']
```

Comment: Why would you not want to use the regular expression library?

Comment: @DanielButler, because it looks like it can work without an additional library. But yes, depends on input.

Comment: Ok I didn’t know if I was missing something

Answer (score 1):

The approach of the below script is to first strip off the leading `term:\n` in this case `Buy:\n`.  Then, we use `re.findall` with the following pattern to find all matches:

```
(.+?)\s*(?:\n|$)
```

This says to capture anything up until the first optional whitespace character, which is then followed by a newline, or the end of the string.

```
product_list = 'Buy:\n Milk \nYoughurt 4 \nBread  \nSausages 4     \nBanana '
product_list = re.sub(r'^[^\s]*\s+', '', product_list)

matches = re.findall(r'(.+?)\s*(?:\n|$)', product_list)
print(matches)

['Milk', 'Youghurt 4', 'Bread', 'Sausages 4', 'Banana']
```

Comment: What does the first '?' in `(.+?)\s*(?:\n|$)` mean?

Comment: Oh, I get it. The `+?` is non greedy operator which stops when it finds a first `\s`. https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Answer (score 0):

This example can be done without a regex, split on `:` and then `\n`

```
actual_list = 'Buy:\n Milk \nYoughurt 4 \nBread  \nSausages 4     \nBanana '
product_list = actual_list.split(':')[1]
processed_list = [product.strip() for product in product_list.split('\n') if product.strip() != '']
print(processed_list)
#['Milk', 'Youghurt 4', 'Bread', 'Sausages 4', 'Banana']
```